# Using MariaDb, how can I query a json(longtext) column to check if a given value exists under any key?

Tags: mysql, mariadb, mariadb-10.3

I have this json data in a 'name' column, where the names of some records are stored with multi-lang support:

```
{"en":"Professional Association","de":"Berufsverband","uk":null}
```

When I run this query returns 0 records:

```
select * from `some_table` where lower(json_value(name,'$.*')) like lower('%Berufsverband%');
```

But if I run the query specifying the lang key **(de)** it works:

```
select * from `some_table` where lower(json_value(name,'$.de')) like lower('%Berufsverband%');
```

My question is, how can I properly use the `$.*` wildcard on MariaDB?

If I run the exact same query on MySQL it works fine:

```
select * from `some_table` where lower(json_unquote(name->'$.*')) like lower('%Berufsverband%');
```

Comment: *how can I properly use the $.* wildcard on MariaDB?* Simply look what is `json_value(name,'$.*')` (execute `select *, json_value(name,'$.*') from some_table;`).

Comment: Do not use LOWER(), specify correct collation instead.

Comment: What are you expecting to return? the entire JSON from the row? a specific key? etc?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a combination of [JSON_CONTAINS](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/json_contains/) and [JSON_EXTRACT](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/json_extract/).
You cannot use wildcards within `JSON_CONTAINS`, but  you can within `JSON_EXTRACT`, so, if you wrap the contains with an extract using a wild card (*see Object Member Selector in [JSONPath Expression](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/jsonpath-expressions/#object-member-selector) below*) you will return the rows containing the value you're searching for.

> **Object Member Selector**
>
> To select member(s) in a JSON object, one can use one of the
> following:
>
> - .memberName selects the value of the member with name memberName.
> - ."memberName" - the same as above but allows one to select a member    with a name that's not a valid identifier (that is, has
>   space, dot,    and/or other characters)
> - .* - selects the values of all members of the object.

```
select * from `some_table` 
WHERE JSON_CONTAINS(JSON_EXTRACT(name, "$.*"), '"Berufsverband"')
```

db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.3&fiddle=723de6544515ef5280150ea80e422e56).

Answer (score 0):

I just made it work, I replaced json_value with json_query. The result was something like this:

```
select * from `some_table` where lower(json_query (name, '$')) like lower('%Berufsverband%');
```

Now it works as expected.